# Calendar Object seams not to be handed to the method using Android and datepicker

Tags: java, android, calendar

I have a silly beginner question.
I am using the Andriod datepicker to do some data entry. Overall I want to store and retrieve data from a firestore db. 
But currently I am struggling with with Calendar and datepicker. The last method (updateDatepickerFromCalendar) is used to update the datapicker with the new data once retrieved. You will not find that one ... but I added a tempory Calendar object which also fails.

The other way around to update the Calendar object from the date picker works perfekt. But if I want to update the date picker from the Calendar object it seams that the calendar object is not handed to the method updateDatepickerFromCalendar while the datepicker object is.

Any Idea what I am doing wrong?

```
        // retrieve data
        ladeknopf.setOnClickListener( (View v) -> {            
         eingabename.setText(datensatz.getNameDerPerson());
        Calendar testDatum;  // just for testing
        testDatum = Calendar.getInstance();
        testDatum.set(1999,11,2);
        updateDatepickerFromCalendar(testDatum, eingabedatum);
        eingabeueberbblick.setText(datensatz.valuesToString());

    });
}

// Datepicker Hilfsmethoden
// calendar object mit Daten aus Datepicker
private void updateCalendarFromDatepicker(Calendar cal3, DatePicker dp){
    cal3.set(Calendar.YEAR, dp.getYear());
    cal3.set(Calendar.MONTH, dp.getMonth());
    cal3.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dp.getDayOfMonth());
}

// here is the issue: pb is handed over but the Calendar Object not
private void updateDatepickerFromCalendar(Calendar cal2, DatePicker dp) {
    dp.updateDate(cal2.YEAR, cal2.MONTH, cal2.DAY_OF_MONTH);

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you use [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) with your Android version? Not that it will solve your issue (likely), but it’s much nicer to work with. The `Calendar` class has some design issues and is long outdated.

Comment: Changed my mind, using java.time *will* solve your issue. An error like using `cal2.YEAR` instead of `cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR)` simply isn’t possible with java.time due to its superior design.

Answer (score 0):

This example can help you.

```
DatePickerDialog[] datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog[1];
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                datePickerDialog[0] = new DatePickerDialog(RegistrationActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                dateOfBirth.setText(year  + "-"+(monthOfYear + 1)
                                        +   "-" + dayOfMonth);

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog[0].show();
```

Comment: How does it help? Asking because I don’t see it and also because an answer should *always* explain how it helps.

Comment: Thank you Ole. Maybe I did not explain my beginner Java question right. I have the impression that in the method "updateDatepickerFromCalendar" the Calendar object is not using the passed object testDatum but the passed object for the datepicker is used.

Comment: Hi, I got the problem. The following line is wrong: 
 `dp.updateDate(cal2.YEAR, cal2.MONTH, cal2.DAY_OF_MONTH);`

and should be replaced by 

 `dp.updateDate(cal2.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal2.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));`